# Jquery icheck plugin

Tags: jqgrid, icheck

I want to apply iCheck style on JqGrid , I tries many solution over the web . I need to set formatter or set column type checkbox.  I tried to set formatter and insert checkbox , also I tried to set type checkbox and set format but if i select checkbox via jquery the style dissappear

```
$.jgrid.defaults.responsive = true;
    $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap';
    jQuery("#grdRoles").jqGrid({
        url: rolesUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { name: 'RoleId', index: 'Id', label: 'Id', search: false, hidden: true, key: true },
            {
                name: 'RoleStatus',
                label: 'RoleStatus',
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'checkbox',
                editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                formatter: "checkbox",
                formatoptions: { disabled: false }


            },
            { name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', label: 'RoleName', width: 80, search: false },
        ],

        onSelectRow: function (rowid, state) {


            var $RowIdValue = $("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + rowid)).next("a");
            var SelecterId = $RowIdValue.prevObject[0];
            var $a = $("div.icheckbox_flat-green")
            $.each($a, function (index) {
                var item = $a[index];
                $.each(item.children, function (index1) {

                    var childrenitem = item.children[index1];
                    if (childrenitem === SelecterId) {

                        if (state) {
                            item.className = "icheckbox_flat-green checked";
                        } else {
                            item.className = "icheckbox_flat-green";
                        }
                    }

                })

            });

        },
        loadComplete: function () {

            var $checkboxes = $("#grdRoles [name=RoleStatus]");
            //$checkboxes.prettyCheckable();
            $checkboxes.iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
            });


            //var $checkboxes = $("#grdRoles input[type=checkbox]");
            //$checkboxes.iCheck({
            //    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
            //    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
            //});

            //$checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function (event) {
            //   console.log('check')
            //});


        }

    });
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or  jqGrid <=4.7. More information  on iCheck style - what is this, which resources are used and...

Comment: version of icheck from script file itself : 
 * iCheck v1.0.2, http://git.io/arlzeA
 * Powerful jQuery and Zepto plugin for checkboxes and radio buttons 
    customization
 * (c) 2013 Damir Sultanov, http://fronteed.com
 * MIT Licensed

Comment: version of JgGrid is Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I put this 
loadComplete: function () {

```
            var $checkboxes = $("#gridId [type=checkbox]");

            $checkboxes.iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
            });
        and it works fine and note it is better not to check , uncheck checkboxes using jquery i think this make some conflict.
```